# Thomas Solver Algorithm Python 3

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, numpy

I need to write a program implementing the Thomas algorithm. My program compile just fine but when i compared to the np.linalg.solve function in numpy im getting to different results for the same system

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np

## Tri Diagonal Matrix Algorithm(a.k.a Thomas algorithm) solver
def TDMAsolver(a, b, c, d):

    nf = len(d) # number of equations
    ac, bc, cc, dc = map(np.array, (a, b, c, d)) # copy arrays
    for it in range(1, nf):
        mc = ac[it-1]/bc[it-1]
        bc[it] = bc[it] - mc*cc[it-1] 
        dc[it] = dc[it] - mc*dc[it-1]

    xc = bc
    xc[-1] = dc[-1]/bc[-1]

    for il in range(nf-2, -1, -1):
        xc[il] = (dc[il]-cc[il]*xc[il+1])/bc[il]

    return xc
```

And here is how  I'm testing it

```
a = np.array([3,3,3,3])
c = np.array([2,2,2,2])
d = np.array([2,2,2,2])
b = np.array([12,17,14,7])

x = TDMAsolver(a,d,c,b)

print(x)
```

The output is

```
[5 1 0 2]
```

While when I do

```
a = np.array([3,3,3,3])
c = np.array([2,2,2,2])
d = np.array([2,2,2,2])
b = np.array([12,17,14,7])

A = np.diag(a,0) + np.diag(c[1:],-1) + np.diag(d[1:],1)
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
print(x)
```

The output is

```
[ 2.  3.  2.  1.]
```

Any guess why is that?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of the `np.linalg.solve` call is what you need to get.

There are two issues with your function:

- when it is called with numpy arrays of type `int`, all assignments to (copies of them) will result in `int` as well, which means the fractional parts are lost in the intermediate calculations.
- it uses its second argument as the main diagonal (i.e. `[2,2,2,2]`), while you pass to `np.linalg.solve` a matrix where `[3,3,3,3]` is the main diagonal.

I would also suggest to use the same naming convention in your global scope as in your function, because as you have it right now, you call the right hand side of the equation *b* in the global scope, but in the function it is called *d*. And what is *d* in the global scope is *b* in the function. This does not help to get grips of your code.

#### 1. Avoid truncation to integer

The first problem becomes evident when you look at this assignment:

```
bc[it] = bc[it] - mc*cc[it-1]
```

In the first iteration, this evaluates to

```
bc[it] = 3 - 0.6666666667 * 2
```

which should be 1.6666666667, but if you would inspect the value of `bc[it]` after the assignment, you would see it got value 1. This is because the numpy array holds integer typed values.

This can be solved by replacing this:

```
ac, bc, cc, dc = map(np.array, (a, b, c, d))
```

with:

```
ac, bc, cc, dc = (x.astype(float) for x in (a, b, c, d))
```

#### 2. Name and pass the variables right

The equation you want to solve looks like this:

```
( 3 2 0 0 )   ( x0 )   ( 12 )
( 2 3 2 0 ) . ( x1 ) = ( 17 )
( 0 2 3 2 )   ( x2 )   ( 14 )
( 0 0 2 3 )   ( x3 )   (  7 )
```

Your function expects these values to be present in the arguments as follows

```
( b0 c0 0  0  )   ( x0 )   ( d0 )
( a0 b1 c1 0  ) . ( x1 ) = ( d1 )
( 0  a1 b2 c2 )   ( x2 )   ( d2 )
( 0  0  a2 b3 )   ( x3 )   ( d3 )
```

Harmonise the global names with that, and give the right size to the arrays -- there are two arrays that should have one element less:

```
a = np.array([2,2,2])
b = np.array([3,3,3,3]) # main diagonal
c = np.array([2,2,2])
d = np.array([12,17,14,7]) # right side of equation

x = TDMAsolver(a,b,c,d) # pass in same order

print(x)
```

And in order to match the naming convention and shorter arrays, adapt the verifying part of your code as follows:

```
A = np.diag(b,0) + np.diag(a,-1) + np.diag(c,1)
x = np.linalg.solve(A,b)
print(x)
```

The solution in both cases is now:

```
x == [ 2.  3.  2.  1.]
```

See it run on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/imOInp)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are tangled in diagonal and right column arrays destination (naming, assignment?).

If b is main diagonal, a is bottom one, c is upper one, d is right column

```
b c 0 0       d
a b c 0       d 
0 a b c       d
0 0 a b       d
```

then your code looks right. But what about matrix A constriction for linalg.solve? Could you print ready matrix and check for element positions?

Comment: Sorry this is the system I am trying to solve (LaTex format)

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc} 3 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\ 2 & 3 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 & 3 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 & 2 & 3 \end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{c} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \\ x_4 \end{array}\right] = 
\left[\begin{array}{c} 12 \\ 17 \\ 14 \\ 7\end{array}\right].$$

Comment: seems here 12-17-15 is right part, but in Thomas algorithm implementation  12-17-15  is the main diagonal